# How does gMapping work?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

New to ROS. Can someone give me a VERY simple explanation of gmapping and its algorithm (how it works)? Just trying to get an extremely basic grasp of how it works.

Here are some links I looked at to try and understand it more:

http://www.openslam.org/gmapping.html

[http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pabbeel/cs287-fa11/slides/gmapping.pdf](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Epabbeel/cs287-fa11/slides/gmapping.pdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239143/how-does-gmapping-work?/) by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure I can add much to the slides you included in your question, but maybe I can simplify and rephrase. Here goes:

GMapping solves the Simultaneous Localization and Mapping (SLAM) problem. Unlike, say [Karto](http://wiki.ros.org/open_karto), it employs a [Particle Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filtering) (PF), which is a technique for model-based estimation. In SLAM, we are estimating two things: the map and the robot's pose within this map. You can kind of think of each particle in the PF as a candidate solution to the problem. Together, the set of particles approximates the true probability distribution (see [Importance Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling)). To clarify, I'm talking about the probability of the map and the robot's pose given the control inputs (e.g. motor encoder counts) and sensor readings (e.g. LiDAR). In addition, there's a motion model and a sensor model involved in the calculation of the probability distribution.

GMapping is much more sophisticated than the outline I gave above. If you are interested, check out one of the research papers describing the approach: [TRO 2007](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Estachnis/pdf/grisetti07tro.pdf) I also highly recommend the chapter on SLAM in the book [Probabilistic Robotics](http://probabilistic-robotics.org/).

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-07-11**:
Probablistic Robotics is a great book